# d3fc.js Setting class for a line series in d3fc JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, d3fc

How do I add a class to a chart in d3fc.js? I am trying to add a simple class to an SVG element in d3fc. I've found examples using inline css `.style`, but I want to add a class. Is that possible with d3fc.js?

I am working on an OHLC (candlestick) chart. I have a line that will be a moving average. I want that line to be a specific color. I want to add a class, what's the best way?

This line will live on an `seriesSvgMulti`

```js
  const line = fc.seriesSvgLine()
                 .mainValue(d => d.ma_high)
                 .crossValue(d => d.date);
```

Comment: It's not clear, I'm assuming the answer is no, if external CSS would work with the canvas rendering output using d3fc. That's OK in this case if true. That external CSS doesn't apply to canvas rendered version. This is specifically for SVG output.

Answer (score 2):

Can add a css class name using d3 and isn't d3fc specific. It uses a decorator to enter the chart 'dom' and select the SVG element where a class is added using the d3 .classed() method

```js
  const line = fc.seriesSvgLine()
                 .decorate(function(selection){
     selection.enter().classed('special_line_css_here', true)
     })
                 .mainValue(d => d.line_average)
                 .crossValue(d => d.date);
```